# How to add conditional display to Interactive Grid column if no data returned for particular column

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

I have an Interactive grid based on data table with columns as : HEADER_1,HEADER_2...HEADER_6.

I want conditional display of columns such that if no row is returned for a particular column, i.e. if `select HEADER_6 from data` --> returns null, then HEADER_6 column shouldn't show at all.

I have page items created also for each column for another requirement like P4_HEADER_1...6, so in case they can be used in this also, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to column HEADER_6 in section Server-side condition choose Rows returned and add query:

```
 SELECT 1
 FROM DATA
 WHERE = HEADER_6 IS NOT NULL;
```

Or you can use item in Server-side condition.

Column HEADER_6 will not be displayed if HEADER_6 is null.

Comment: don't think this will work with a partial page refresh. If the user executes a search in the interactive grid and there is data in that column, it will not show because the server side condition is evaluated at page rendering, not for a partial page refresh.

Comment: @KoenLostrie You're right, but that's what was being asked, isn't it? Not a good idea for a report that will change frequently

Comment: SELECT 1
 FROM DATA
 WHERE = HEADER_1 IS NOT NULL; : somehow this is not working for me. For the second solution, i tried using item is not null for HEADER_1 and assign the item :P4_HEADER_1.But that's not working either

Comment: Sorry, I changed code, I tested first solution, it works. If any row in HEADER_6 contain value, column will be displayed, column is hidden only when all rows are null.

Comment: @Peter Simic, true but it is something to keep in mind for interactive reports and interactive grid. The OP might not be aware of this.

Comment: @petar Simic, thanks it worked. You are very good with apex. I have another tricky query. If you don;t mind, could you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609252/oracle-apex-change-dynamically-interactive-grid-column-names